# c header-guards are ignored?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, include-guards

Why does gcc ignore these header guards in this simple test program?

The header file is:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

#warning "header declared"

int some_int=0;

#endif
```

And the two .c files are:
main.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int main ()
{
    return some_int;
}
```

source.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int get_int()
{
    return some_int;
}
```

When compiling with:

```
  gcc -o out main.c source.c
```

I get the following output:

```
In file included from main.c:1:
header.h:4:2: warning: #warning "header declared" [-Wcpp]
    4 | #warning "header declared"
      |  ^~~~~~~
In file included from source.c:1:
header.h:4:2: warning: #warning "header declared" [-Wcpp]
    4 | #warning "header declared"
      |  ^~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmAbN1J.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `some_int'; /tmp/ccEd5PwN.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As expected, the warning shows up, when the compiler includes the header file for the first time. But why wont the header guards stop the second inclusion?

The gcc version is:

```
gcc version 9.2.1 20200130 (Arch Linux 9.2.1+20200130-2)
```

Comment: It is included only once in each translation unit.

Comment: Each file is compiled separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Header guards guard against multiple inclusion in a single translation unit (usually a `.c` file and everything it includes, directly or indirectly).

You have two translation units, `main.c` and `source.c`, and they're compiled independently (even if you use a single command line line `gcc main.c source.c`). That's why you're getting an error message from the linker, not from the compiler.

If you want to *define* an object, you should do it in a `.c` file and declare it as `extern` in the corresponding `.h` file. The `.c` file defining the object is compiled just once, and multiple other `.c` files can see the declaration in the `.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ignoring them. You have two separate compilation units there and each one needs `header.h`. Header guards are intended to prevent a single compilation unit from including the same header twice. For example. If `main.c` included `header.h' directly, but also included`foo.h`which also included`header.h`, when all the includes are expanded the header guard ensures that`header.h`'s contents only appear once.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 compilation units : 1 for `main.c` and 1 for `source.c`. These are compiled separately (and completely independently) by the compiler, resulting in 2 object files (eg. `main.o` resp. `source.o`). Each of these prints the warning :

```
In file included from main.c:1:
header.h:4:2: warning: #warning "header declared" [-Wcpp]
    4 | #warning "header declared"
      |  ^~~~~~~
```

These object files are then linked into an executable `out` by the linker.

But the linker discovers that both object files define the same symbol `some_int`, and thus fails to generate the executable, resulting in :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmAbN1J.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `some_int'; /tmp/ccEd5PwN.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```